# Python Socket: Compare Responses of Two Clients

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, client, server, multiplayer

I made a simple text based game and I want to create a multi-player mode to it.
I have a server and two clients:
CLIENT1 ----> SERVER <---- CLIENT2
Client1 sends number 7 to the server and Client2 sends number 5 to the server.
CLIENT1 -- 7 --> SERVER <-- 5 -- CLIENT2
Then the server add this numbers (7+5=12) and send this as a response to the clients.
CLIENT1 <-- 12 -- SERVER -- 12 --> CLIENT2
My question is how can I do this?

UPDATE
I've found a solution:

```
# -*-coding:utf8;-*-

import socket
import sys
from thread import *

HOST = ''
PORT = 3737

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(10)

def clientthread(conn):
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n')

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        return data
    conn.close()
n = 0
l = []
while n < 2:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    d = clientthread(conn)
    l.append(d)
    print l[n]
    n = n + 1
player1, player2 = int(l[0]), int(l[1])
```

Comment: kindly provide some code of what you tried so far

Comment: Thanks for your help! Today I found a solution. I've edited my question.